# Angular 4 view is not updating with the change made in array

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to Angular 4. It is quite great framework by Google.

I have a component which calls a REST api to receives back some JSON data and my model is being updated, however, the view isn't changing. I have gone through the various resources and got some references of ChangeDetectorRef component of @angular/core lib.

However after injecting the ChangeDetectorRef with parent component and opening a dailog of child component, I get No provider for ChangeDetectorRef in console, and the dialog doesn't get open correctly and get merge to left end.

I have tried to add the ChangeDetectorRef component in app.module.ts provider:[ChangeDetectorRef] block but its shows error in webstrom and angular cli could not compile the file.

How can I solve this issue to get the update model value repeated in the view part of HTML?

My app.module.ts looks like:

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [

    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],

imports: [

BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
CovalentLayoutModule,
CovalentStepsModule,
CovalentMenuModule,
MdIconModule,
MdSidenavModule,
MdToolbarModule,
MdButtonModule,
MdListModule,
MdMenuModule,
MdGridListModule,
FlexLayoutModule,
routing,
MdTabsModule,
CovalentDataTableModule,
CovalentSearchModule,
CovalentPagingModule,
CovalentLoadingModule,
CovalentDialogsModule,
MdSelectionModule,
MdSelectModule,
MdSlideToggleModule,
HttpModule,
CovalentDynamicFormsModule,
ToastModule.forRoot()],

entryComponents: 
[
AppDailogComponent,
],

providers: [
AjaxService,ChangeDetectorRef],

bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

How can I add **ChangeDetectorRef** to the providers to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you add the code of the component using the ChangeDetectorRef ?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the changeDetection in your @component decorator and try using this,

however change detection is a dearly operation for any frontend. If you know your component well enough I suggest you to run it locally like this ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(), in AngularJS it used to be like $scope.$digest()

if you want to run a detection for the entire application like $rootscope.$apply, go for NgZone.run(yourCallbackMethod).

You can also do ApplicationRef.tick(), which I believe similar to $rootScope.$apply().

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This apporach already implemented and was not successful. Well got the solution as it was a dailog, so need to call the **dailog.AfterCloseAll()** function to make the required function fire on close of dailog